# Is it possible to remove the current user from a GeoFirestore query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, geofirestore

**If you are querying users in a 100km radius how do you exclude yourself (the current user) from the query?**

Because when onDocumentMoved triggers if you are the only one moving you trigger on document entered you will get the users again but with different distance between you and the users, thus you will get duplicate results if you are adding them to the database in the onDocumentEntered method. The way I solved it is deleting all the usersInRange from the database when the app is opened again. I know this is not the perfect solution and I am seeking a better one.

Here is my code that does this:

```
  public void getLocation(Location location){
    ArrayList<String> docMoved = new ArrayList<>();
    listenerRegistration = documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(value != null && value.exists()){
                if (value.get("LocationRange") != null && value.get("AgeRangeFrom") != null && value.get("AgeRangeTo") != null && value.getString("InterestInGender") != null) {
                    locationRange = (double) value.get("LocationRange");
                    ageRangeFrom = (double) value.get("AgeRangeFrom");
                    ageRangeTo = (double) value.get("AgeRangeTo");
                    interestInGender = value.getString("InterestInGender");
                    ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>> usersInRange = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) value.get("UsersInRange");

                    geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), locationRange);

                    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDocumentEntered(@NotNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot5, @NotNull GeoPoint geoPoint) {
                            if (documentSnapshot5.get("age") != null && documentSnapshot5.getString("Gender") != null && documentSnapshot5.get("Images") != null && !documentSnapshot5.getId().equals(user.getUid())) {
                                age = (long) documentSnapshot5.get("age");
                                userGender = documentSnapshot5.getString("Gender");
                                userPhotos = (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot5.get("Images");

                                Location locationNew = new Location(documentSnapshot5.getId());
                                locationNew.setLatitude(geoPoint.getLatitude());
                                locationNew.setLongitude(geoPoint.getLongitude());

                                distanceM = location.distanceTo(locationNew);
                                distanceKM = (int) Math.round(distanceM / 1000);


                                if (age >= ageRangeFrom && age <= ageRangeTo && interestInGender.equals("Women") && userGender.equals("Woman")) {
                                    db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayUnion(new User(documentSnapshot5.getString("Name"), age, userPhotos.get(0), documentSnapshot5.getId(), distanceKM, null)));
                                } else if (age >= ageRangeFrom && age <= ageRangeTo && interestInGender.equals("Men") && userGender.equals("Man")) {
                                    db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayUnion(new User(documentSnapshot5.getString("Name"), age, userPhotos.get(0), documentSnapshot5.getId(), distanceKM, null)));
                                } else if (age >= ageRangeFrom && age <= ageRangeTo && interestInGender.equals("Everyone")) {
                                    db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayUnion(new User(documentSnapshot5.getString("Name"), age, userPhotos.get(0), documentSnapshot5.getId(), distanceKM, null)));
                                } else {
                                    db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayRemove(new User(documentSnapshot5.getString("Name"), age, userPhotos.get(0), documentSnapshot5.getId(), distanceKM, null)));
                                }
                            }


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDocumentExited(@NotNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1) {
                            db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>> usersInRange = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) documentSnapshot.get("UsersInRange");
                                    if (usersInRange != null && !usersInRange.isEmpty()) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < usersInRange.size(); i++) {
                                            if (usersInRange.get(i).containsValue(documentSnapshot1.getId())) {
                                                db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayRemove(usersInRange.get(i)));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onDocumentMoved(@NotNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot6, @NotNull GeoPoint geoPoint) {
                            docMoved.add(documentSnapshot6.getId());
                            if(!documentSnapshot6.getId().equals(user.getUid())) {
                                db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                        ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>> usersInRange = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) documentSnapshot.get("UsersInRange");
                                        if (usersInRange != null && !usersInRange.isEmpty()) {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < usersInRange.size(); i++) {
                                                if (usersInRange.get(i).containsValue(documentSnapshot6.getId())) {
                                                    db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayRemove(usersInRange.get(i)));
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDocumentChanged(@NotNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1, @NotNull GeoPoint geoPoint) {
                            if(docMoved.size() == 1 && docMoved.get(0).equals(user.getUid())){
                                db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.delete());
                            }
                            db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>> usersInRange = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) documentSnapshot.get("UsersInRange");
                                    if (usersInRange != null && !usersInRange.isEmpty()) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < usersInRange.size(); i++) {
                                            if (usersInRange.get(i).containsValue(documentSnapshot1.getId())) {
                                                db.collection("UsersFilter").document(user.getUid()).update("UsersInRange", FieldValue.arrayRemove(usersInRange.get(i)));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryError(@NotNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code that displays the users in a ViewPager2:

```
       listenerRegistration = documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            if(value != null && value.exists()) {
                usersInRange = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) value.get("UsersInRange");
                usersInChat = (ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>>) value.get("UsersInChat");

                imageUrls.clear();
                viewPager2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (usersInChat != null && !usersInChat.isEmpty() && usersInRange != null && !usersInRange.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < usersInChat.size(); i++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < usersInRange.size(); k++) {
                            if (usersInRange.get(k).containsValue(usersInChat.get(i).get("userID"))) {
                                usersInRange.remove(usersInRange.get(k));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (usersInRange != null && !usersInRange.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < usersInRange.size(); i++) {
                        String profileImage = (String) usersInRange.get(i).get("profilePic");
                        String userName = (String) usersInRange.get(i).get("name");
                        long userAge = (long) usersInRange.get(i).get("age");
                        String userID = (String) usersInRange.get(i).get("userID");
                        long km = (long) usersInRange.get(i).get("km");

                        imageUrls.add(new User(userName, userAge, profileImage, userID, km, null));

                        viewPager2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```